# query.ref.removeValue removes the entire child instead of just a node

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to remove one specific node from my database by querying and then calling the `query.ref.removeValue()` though every time this piece of code runs it deletes the entire child instead of just the node. My code looks like this...

```
let query = (ref?.child("Groups").child("Martins").child("Messages").queryEqualToValue(selectedValue))

query!.ref.removeValue()
```

My database is looking like this...

[image: It starts with the child named "Groups" then another which is the name of the group then a child named "Messages" and inside I want to be able to individuall delete the nodes instead of deleting the whole Messages child.]

Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

The query reference points to the location that the query is defined on, not to the elements that it matches. So `query!.ref.removeValue()` will remove the entire location.

To remove the individual items that the query matches, you'll need to attach a listener to the query and iterate over the children:

```
let query = ref?.child("Groups").child("Martins").child("Messages")
                .queryOrderedByKey("Item").queryEqualToValue(selectedValue)

query.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
  snapshot.ref.removeValue()
})
```

Comment: Yeah, you were missing a `queryOrderedByKey` in there too it seems. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: This fix does not work for me, when I add the code in it does not delete anything from Firebase...

Comment: OK, thanks for trying. Did you try debugging it? Is the query not matching any of your elements? Or does the `removeValue()` not delete the item?

Comment: The removeValue() just doesnt delete the item. Though I know it isn't because it doesn't match a value because if I change .ChildAdded to .Value it deletes the entire child again.

Comment: I was just wondering if you had figured something else out because I am still having trouble with this same problem... I have tried looking everywhere for answers but I am having trouble finding a good answer.