# Firebase: query and delete keys in a range

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have some data in the Firebase real-time database like this

```
root--.
      |--stuff--.
                |--1
                |--2
                |--3
                |--4
                |--5
                |--6
                |--7
```

where all those numbers are keys that contain more data, and I want to delete all the keys less than or equal to 4, how do I do that without downloading the entire "stuff" branch?

With swift I think I can query the keys in that range by

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("stuff")
let query = ref.queryEnding(atValue: 4)
```

but I don't know how to retrieve the key names themselves so that I can delete them sort of like this pseudocode

```
for key in queryResults {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("stuff/\(key)")
    ref.setValue(nil) 
}
```

(In reality I'm dealing with timestamp keys and I want to delete data branches that have gotten too old.)

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835857/query-ref-removevalue-removes-the-entire-child-instead-of-just-a-node

Comment: Sound like you are on the right track. Query for the first 4 nodes and then delete them using their keys - see my code snippet answer. Is there something more to it?

Comment: How do I query for those first 4 nodes? I don't think ref.queryEnding(atValue: 4) is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it in swift, but you can do it with orderByKey.

```
    .database().reference()
    .child("stuff")
    .orderByKey()
    .startAt(STARTING_TIMESTAMP)
    .endAt(ENDING_TIMESTAMP)
```

And then loop over the ids of the corresponding result.

This will download all information for those children though. If you don't want that you'll have to store it somewhere else to easily delete it.

Comment: Having a separate branch just to store nothing but timestamp-keys for garbage collection later on is actually seeming like a pretty good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Swift 3 / Firebase 2.x code to get the keys from a snapshot

```
for child in (snapshot?.children)! {           
     let snap = child as! FDataSnapshot
     print(snap.key)                 
}
```

Comment: I think that would download not just the keys but also their children, which is not optimal.

Comment: @user3915477 That's correct. Your question states you wanted to avoid downloading the whole stuff branch and didn't know how to get the keys. Per my comment, you would only download the 4 you want to delete then iterate over them with the code in my answer. I can expand on that code if you need to see how to do the actual query as well. As a side note, there is no way to download just the keys - the way around that is to simply keep a duplicate node with just keys in it. Get the ones you want to delete from there and then delete them in both nodes.

Comment: I'm going to try and implement that separate branch of keys for expiration handling solution. It seems like an acceptable workaround. Thanks.